# VSCode debug mode does not set os.getcwd() to the one specified in launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug my python program in VSCode where I'm getting its directory. When I run `os.getcwd()` from the terminal, I get the correct directory, but when I use the VS Code debug option, it defaults to the "default" path (as set in my registry variable, which is C:\Users<User>\Downloads).

I have created a launch.json file.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "C:\\Users\\<User>\\Documents\\Project\\"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I added "cwd", except no matter what value I put here, the value of `os.getcwd()` returns the default path in debug mode. I have tried putting: the whole path, `${workspaceFolder}`, `${fileDirname}`, `${fileWorkspaceFolder}`.

The launch.json file is in the .vscode folder in my project.

I do not understand why this is happening and would ideally like a fix. None of the other questions on this site on this subject were able to help.

Answer (score 2):

For those that might have the same problem in the future, I found a work-around. (This works without `launch.json`.)

I manually edited the code from: `directory = os.getcwd()` to:

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(dir_path)
directory = os.getcwd()
```

Then the debugger is in the current working directory and is able to see the files I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

Please use settings similar to the following in "`launch.json`":

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\a_pythonscript",
```

[image]

When my "main.py" is in the folder "demo_csv" and "lauch.json" uses `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\demo",`:

[image]

Since the python debugging function in VS Code is provided by the Python extension, please try to reinstall the Python extension.

Comment: this is not helpful: I already said that ${workspaceFolder} didn't return the working directory, just the default one. In your example, your default directory happens to be a parent of your working directory. Mine aren't.